# Why am I getting large reaped ints?

Tags: c, fork, posix

I'm working on a project for class that is supposed to take numbers from the command line, fork, and then pass them to be added by the child process then the parent is supposed to reap the sum of the numbers. It seems to be working well enough except when I reap the child process it gives me large numbers instead of the sum of the numbers it added together originally. If I just put in 0 I get 0 and if I put in 1 I get 256 and so on. What am I missing am I just not reaping correctly? Thanks.

```
enter code // Numbers from command line arguments are sent to child process
// from parent process one at a time through pipe.
//
// Child process adds up numbers sent through pipe.
//
// Child process returns sum of numbers to parent process.
//
// Parent process prints sum of numbers.


static int  com[2];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t   pid;

    // set up pipe

    if (pipe(com))
    {
       printf("pipe error\n");
       return -1;
     }

    //call fork()

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0)
    {
        // -- running in child process --

        int             sum = 0;
        int             input = 0;

        //close output end of pipe

        close(com[1]);

        // Receive characters from parent process via pipe
        // one at a time, and count them.

        for (int idx = 1; idx < argc; idx++) //stared idx at 1 instead of 0
        {
                read(com[0], &input, 4); //changed from 4
                sum = sum + input;
        }
                printf("child sum: %i \n", sum); // error checking

        // Return sum of numbers.

        return sum;
    }
    else {
            // -- running in parent process --

            int sum;

            //close output end of pipe

            close(com[0]);

            // Send numbers (datatype: int, 4 bytes) from command line arguments
            // starting with argv[1] one at a time through pipe to child process.

            for (int idx = 1; idx < argc; idx++)
            {
                    int output = 0;

                    output = atoi(argv[idx]);
                    write(com[1], &output, 4);
                    printf("output: %i \n", output);// error checking
            }

            close(com[1]);

            // Wait for child process to return. Reap child process.
            // Receive sum of numbers via the value returned when
            // the child process is reaped.

            waitpid(pid, &sum, 0);

            printf("sum = %d\n", sum);

            return 0;
       }
 }
```

here

Comment: Seems it's shifting my bits over.

Comment: The exit status is stored in the high-order 8 bits of the exit status, effectively multiplying your sum by 256.  Your sum is also limited to 255.

Comment: You'd better read standard output of child process. First is is easier to test and it allows you to accept sums greater than 256. The *status* returned by a command is only intended to be a status: use it for error conditions, but use stdout for meaningful data.

Answer (score 4):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

> If status is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information in the int to which it points. This integer can be inspected with the following macros

two of which are

```
WIFEXITED(status)
    returns true if the child terminated normally, that is, by
    calling exit(3) or _exit(2), or by returning from main().

WEXITSTATUS(status)
    returns the exit status of the child. This consists of the
    least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child
    specified in a call to exit(3) or _exit(2) or as the argument
    for a return statement in main(). This macro should only be
    employed if WIFEXITED returned true.
```